# How can I increase space below axis for long date strings?

Tags: javascript, echarts

[image: Echarts cutting of the bottom Xaxis fields]

Please look at the picture and let me know if there is an option to increase the margin/border of this image to accommodate for the long date/time string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can set `grid` option can achieve this goal:

```
grid.containLabel = true
```

if you like, can also set:

```
grid.bottom = 0
```

for example:

```
    option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        axisLabel: {
            interval: 1,
            rotate: 45
        },
        data: ['2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04', '2018-06-07 14:27:04']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    grid: {
        bottom: 0,
        containLabel: true
    },
    series: [{
        data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320, 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320, 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320, 820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320,820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true
    }]
};
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Really Sorry. Using Margin/ Border we can't do any thing because we having lots of data.Already we having lots of xAxis labels in that image.

One thing we can do for this. why can't you try this kind of charts

https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=candlestick-brush

at the bottom of the chart it will have handle to change the range of the xAxis.

[image]

Hope you like this solution.